# Reference app location in a Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I have a blueprint where I have an upload form.  I am attempting to save the files, but I cannot figure out how to reference the correct directory.  When I use app.instance_path, it gives the error message:

NameError: name 'app' is not defined

How can I declare the correct folder location to store the file from within a Flask Blueprint?

Here is my init.py file:

```
# External libraries
from flask import Flask


# Import the resources
from . import students

def create_app(configfile=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.register_blueprint(students.bp)

    return app
```

Here is my students.py blueprint file:

```
import os

from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)

from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

from SIMPLE.forms import ImportStudentsForm

bp = Blueprint('students', __name__, url_prefix='/students')

@bp.route('/import', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def import_students():
    # Load the register form
    form = ImportStudentsForm(request.form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(
            app.instance_path, 'uploads',  filename
        ))

        # Flash success
        flash('Sucessfully registered.', 'success')

    return render_template('students/batch_import_students.html', form=form)
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you have not imported `app` in `students.py`. You could import it (and run the risk of circular imports) but a more elegant way is to get the app instance through `flask.current_app`.

Add `from flask import current_app` to the top of `students.py` and replace `app.instance_path` with `current_app.instance_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
from flask import current_app
```

AND

```
f.save(os.path.join(current_app.instance_path, 'uploads',  filename))
```

You are using application factory. So there is no 'app' object here. Whatever app flask is currently using can be fetched with `current_app` and then you can work with it.

Also, if the `instance_path` doesn't work, try `current_app.root_path`